# Excel File Upload Changing Data Type

Tags: c#

I have to upload excel files, I have excel files with a proper format, I have a column which contains large numbers,so in excel it is displaying the numbers with Exponent, For eg I have this value  8.99681E+18(8996812351321100000)

I am making DataTable by reading it on runtime,After making Datatable,this value got changed with (8996812351321100288).
This is how I am doing

```
var conn = new OleDbConnection();
 if (fileExtension == ".xls")
      //4.0 Connection String
 if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                //12.0 Connection String

           conn.Open();
            DataTable dtSheets = conn.GetSchema("Tables");
            string firstSheet = dtSheets.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            using (var comm = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                comm.CommandText = "select * from [" + firstSheet + "]";
                comm.Connection = conn;                
                using (var da = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                {
                    da.SelectCommand = comm;
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    if (dt.Columns.Contains("SIMNo"))
                    {
                        DataTable dtCloned = dt.Clone();
                        dtCloned.Columns["SIMNo"].DataType = typeof(Int64);
                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
                        }
                        return dtCloned;
                    }
                    return dt;
                }
            }
```

Is there a way that I can change the data type of SIMNo at runtime before creaating DataTable?and how can I do that?

Comment: casting 8996812351321100000 to a double from a long yields 8,9968123513211E+18, is that what you want instead of what ever you're trying to do here?

Comment: Where does the problem occur? Is it in `dt` or in `dtCloned`?

Comment: @TimRogers its in dtCloned

Comment: I am casting 8,9968123513211E+18 to double,and its giving me  8996812351321100288 instead of  8996812351321100000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting `8996812351321100000.0` to `Int64` gives a precision rounding error.

```
(Int64)8996812351321100000.0 // == 8996812351321100288
```

Instead, use the `decimal` datatype as it is designed to represent decimal numbers without rounding issues. Or, as it's a number that will not have any arithmetic applied to it, just use a `string`.

Comment: so I should use decimal or string instead of Int64?

Comment: Casting in string is taking the number as it is with Exponent,I want it without exponent like(8996812351321100000) (without decimal)

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi Either manually convert it or use `decimal` then.

Answer (score 1):

I think, BigInt should be a help.

```
http://www.carljohansen.co.uk/bigint/.
```